# Create a mutable Generator class

Tags: python

I have created a class which receives a CSV file content, validates each row using a pydantic model, and fills two attribute lists with valid or invalid rows. I want to improve this logic converting these two attribute lists into two generators, but I don't know how to make it in a memory efficient way.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from collections import UserList
from typing import Iterable, Mapping

from pydantic import ValidationError

from models.ValidRow import ValidRow
from models.InvalidRow import InvalidRow

class CSVFile:
    class ValidRows(UserList):
        def to_csv(self) -> str:
            output = StringIO()
            header = ValidRow.get_output_header()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, header)
            writer.writeheader()
            
            for row in self.data:
                writer.writerow(row)

            return output.getvalue()

    class InvalidRows(UserList):
        def to_csv(self) -> str:
            output = StringIO()
            header = InvalidRow.get_output_header()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, header)
            writer.writeheader()
            
            for row in self.data:
                writer.writerow(row)

            return output.getvalue()

    def __init__(self, rows: Iterable[Mapping]) -> None:
        self.valid_rows: CSVFile.ValidRows = self.ValidRows()
        self.invalid_rows: CSVFile.InvalidRows = self.InvalidRows()
        
        for row in rows:
            try:
                valid_row = ValidRow(**row)
                self.valid_rows.append(valid_row.dict())
            except ValidationError as e:
                invalid_row = InvalidRow(**row)
                self.invalid_rows.append(invalid_row.dict())
```

As you can see, my `ValidRows` and `InvalidRows` classes are extending `UserList` class, so they are actually lists. I would like to achieve something similar but with the `Generator` class instead, but I can't figure out how I should code it. I guess it should look something like this:

```
class ValidRows(collections.abc.Generator):
    def send(self, value) -> None:
        # no idea what I should add here

    def throw(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None) -> None:
        raise StopIteration
```

I want two features:

1. I need to be able of adding data to my generators (something like `.append()` for lists) because I will fill them row by row in the main class `__init__` method.
2. I want to add the same `to_csv()` method I currently have, but accessing the generator data in the `for` loop.

Comment: Do you know how generators (`yield` and `yield from`) work in python?

Comment: I have worked with `yield` statement before although I don't consider myself to have a deep understanding on it, but to be honest it is the first time I have ever seen the `yield from` one @SUTerliakov

Comment: If you want to stick with class-based approach (extending collections.abc.Generator), you can create `DictWriter` inside `ValidRow.__init__`, then `writerow` in `send` and extract `.getvalue()` in any method you like. But you don't really use generators here: just a storage that writes every new piece of data to string buffer. Main generators power is that they can be defined as simple functions and receive `send` as `yield` value (`x = yield 1` inside generator `my_gen` will receive 'foo' when `next_val = my_gen.send('foo')` is called (and `next_val == 1` now). Not so funny in class form.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to work with generators. I want to use all the power of generators, but 1) being able to add elements one by one and 2) define a custom method which will iterate over the generator values and perform an action. Can I create a class (or edit my code in some way) to meet those requirements, are it goes against the generators logic? @SUTerliakov

Comment: the main problem i see is that `valid_rows` and `invalid_rows` are tightly coupled in creation, so making `valid_rows` a generator will prevent `invalid_rows` from being usable until `valid_rows` is fully processed first, so unless you have a very good reason for converting `valid_rows` to a generator (such as running out of memory), i'd rather stick to their current implementation.

Comment: @AhmedAEK That's not a problem since `invalid_rows` should also be a generator, I didn't write its class schema since it would be redundant. The usage I want to give the class is creating a file instance with an input generator, parse each element in the generator and create two output generators on the `valid_rows` and `invalid_rows` attributes,. Data won't be accessed until the initialization has finished

Comment: what I mean is that if someone tries to iterate over `invalid_rows` you have two options, the first is to fully iterate over the input first, which is your current implementation, and the second option is that it will always return nothing until someone uses the `valid_rows` iterator first, so while creating an extendable iterator is simple, creating an iterator that extends another iterator when used is a big mess that none should do.